# reactjs / jest : unable to populate react-apollo component with data using MockedProvider?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, react-apollo, reactjs-testutils

I have written simple react-apollo component which uses graphql query to retrieve data from schema. On execution component works fine but, when I am writing test case for this component using jest framework together with MockedProvider(i.e. component of react-apollo/test-utils). I am unable to populate component with data. I had refered this article on MockedProvider: https://paradite.com/2017/11/16/test-react-apollo-components-enzyme-examples/

my component and test script is as below:

```
//MyComponent.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { gql, graphql, compose } from "react-apollo";

export class MyComp extends Component {

render() {
  console.log("data",this.props);
  return (
    <div>Hello  welcome {this.props.msg}
      {!this.props.data.loading && this.props.data.person.edges.map((person,i)=>(
        <p key={i}>{person.node.name}</p>
      )
    )}
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export const PERSON_QUERY = gql`query Info {
person{
 edges{
   node{
    id
    name
    __typename
   }
  __typename
 }
 __typename
 }
}`;

export default compose(graphql(PERSON_QUERY,{}))(MyComp);
```

//MyComponent.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import toJSON from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils';
import { addTypenameToDocument } from 'apollo-client';
import { gql, graphql, compose } from "react-apollo";
import MyComponent,{MyComp, PERSON_QUERY} from 'components/MyComponent';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
import {store} from "stores/store";

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

const data1 = {
  person: {
   edges: [
    {
      node: {
        id: "00000000-0002-972",
        name: "Magic Mad",
        __typename: "Person"
      },
      __typename: "PersonEdge"
    },
    {
      node: {
        id: "000-0001-972",
        name: "Donald Durm",
        __typename: "Person"
      },
      __typename: "PersonEdge"
    },
    {
      node: {
        id: "00-0000-fccd3",
        name: "Peter Hogwarts",
        __typename: "Person"
      },
      __typename: "PersonEdge"
    }
  ],
  __typename: "PersonConnection"
  }
};

describe("MockedProvider",()=>{
 test("Load with data",()=>{
  const wrap = mount(<MockedProvider mocks={[
   {
    request: {
      query: addTypenameToDocument(PERSON_QUERY)
    },
    result: { data: data1 }
   }
    ]}>
   <MyComponent msg={"2018"}/>
  </MockedProvider>);
 console.log("Mock",wrap.props());
 console.log("html",wrap.html());
 wrap.update();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Author of the post here.

A number of issues that I can see quite easily:

```
result: { data: data2 }
```

where `data2` is not defined, I think you mean `data1`.

Also, your mock data `data1` has a `data` property, which is wrong, because the result object already has a `data` property, you should remove it from `data1` and expose `person` property directly:

```
const data1 = {
  person: {
   edges: [
    {
      node: {
        id: "00000000-0002-972",
        name: "Magic Mad",
        __typename: "Person"
      },
      __typename: "PersonEdge"
    },
    {
      node: {
        id: "000-0001-972",
        name: "Donald Durm",
        __typename: "Person"
      },
      __typename: "PersonEdge"
    },
    {
      node: {
        id: "00-0000-fccd3",
        name: "Peter Hogwarts",
        __typename: "Person"
      },
      __typename: "PersonEdge"
    }
  ],
  __typename: "PersonConnection"
  }
};
```

Another thing you should probably know, in case this still does not solve your issue, is that you can log the `wrap` variable to see the mocks and check if they match what you want:

```
console.log(wrap);
```

You can try to debug from there.

Comment: yes , @paradite I mean data1, I had done with your suggested changes but still not getting mocked data as response

Comment: when I print html() of wrapper I get something like this: <div><!-- react-text: 2 -->Hello  welcome <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3 -->2018<!-- /react-text -->

Comment: But I want to get result like: <div><!-- react-text: 2 -->Hello welcome <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3 -->2018<!-- /react-text --><p>Marcus</p><p>Durms</p><p>Witchcraft</p></div>

Comment: your `org.node.name` is not even defined anyway. please make sure you don't have any syntax errors.

Comment: yes, it should be `person.node.name`. @paradite I had given try to apollo-mocknetworkinterface  lib and my problem is solved. But I couldn't make it out with MockedProvider.